# Write speed to NVME disk degrade after some time of active work

Tags: raid, mdadm, kernel, xfs, nvme

I have a fairly general question, but maybe someone already had similar behavior.
I have few servers with 20 nvme micron 7450 pro 15 TB disks on each. On all servers I created raid 0 using mdadm software (ubuntu 22 system). Then I configured an xfs filesystem for this raid and started testing write speed for such system using the fio software. After booting up the server I can get ~80 GB per second  write speed. But after some time of active work with the server write speed drops and for example after a day I can get maximum 2-6 GB per second write speed. Remounting filesystem does not change this behavior and neither does fstrim, but if I restart server - I can get again ~80 GB per second write speed for some time. This is strange for me. I tried to use different parameters for raid chunk size, different parameters for filesystem (like noatime, discard, sunit, swidth and so on), different parameters for the kernel like dirty pages but non of this helped. Same behavior on all servers(

Maybe someone had experience with the similar problem and have any advise why it could be and how to configure the system correctly (raid, filesystem, kernel parameters)? I understand that I can't get ~80 GB write speed all the time, but why is it so low 2-6, how to stop degrading it and why restart helps for some time?
Thanks in advance)

Comment: Have you configured all layers of your file system (lvm if you're using that, mdadm, xfs) to allow trim commands to pass through?

Comment: I mounted filesystem with discard option and when I run 
lsblk --discard
command, I see that DISC-GRAN (discard granularity) и DISC-MAX (discard max bytes) are not zeros like for example: 
NAME        DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
nvme2n1            0      512B       2T         0
└─md127            0      512B       2T         0
Also I ran manually fstrim and it did not help.